# Why my object doesn't appear after adding second function in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, delay

I wrote a simple function in jquery which adds css class to my div with photo after clicking on a button.
`$('#btn1').click(function(){
 $('#div1').addClass('show'});`

I want this div (actually it's content) to pop up.
CSS:

```
#div1 {
display: none;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
margin: auto;
overflow: auto;
}

.show {
display: block!important;  
}
```

So far works perfectly. But I want this div to dissapear again after 2s so I added this to jquery:

```
$('#btn1').click(function(){
$('#div1').addClass('show').delay(2000).removeClass('show')
});
```

And now it doesn't apper at all. So where is my problem? I tried also with setTimeout:

```
<script>
$('#btn1').click(function(){
$('#div1').addClass('show')
});

setTimeout(function() {
$('#div1').removeClass('show')
}, 2000);
</script>
```

I'm just starting with programming, so I'll be grateful for possibly easiest to understand code. Thanks for all help.

Comment: For starters, at the top of your question, in the second line of code, notice the syntax error with wrong closing brackets.

Comment: `addClass()` does not inherently perform an action based off of an internal queue to jQuery.  `delay()` relies on this.  Since this is the case I assume it it adding and removing the class 'show' immediately.  delay() is not a replacement for setTimeout, which you should use in this case.  http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: Your set timeout logic is outside of the click handler.  Move it inside so it will start waiting when you perform the click logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following. You are actually adding the timeout function outside the button click event. So that actually runs when the page gets loaded and ends before you click the button probably.

```
$('#btn1').click(function(){
  $('#div1').addClass('show');
  setTimeout(function(){$('#div1').removeClass('show');},2000);
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

like @Taplar have pointed out, you can't use `delay()` here because `dalay` will only effect the method that uses the effects queue. Since `addclass` and `removeClass` don't use the effects queue, they will be executed immediately. My suggestion is to use `fadeOut` as I think this is why you want to have the 2000 delay

```
$('#btn1').click(function(){
    $('#div1').show().fadeOut(2000);
});
```

if you insist on using the `dalay` function, you can use it with `fadeOut` too

```
$('#btn1').click(function(){
    $('#div1').show().delay(2000).fadeOut();
});
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/42mr0Z3rKNBZI9Y64enC?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

syntax error, it should be

```
$('#btn1').click(function(){
  $('#div1').addClass('show');
});
```